# Viewing/retrieveing the values for goodness of fit, using the fitlm function

Tags: matlab, regression, curve-fitting

I am using the `fitlm` function within Matlab for some simple linear regressions.

Context: I have three sets of data for my observed 'X' values, into which my intercepts are already baked, and so I am setting my intercept in `fitlm` for the regressions to zero.

I would simply like to retrieve the value of the coefficient, `b`, and the values for goodness of fit, i.e. `mdl.Rsquared.Ordinary` and `mdl.Rsquared.Adjusted` - which I believe I can do.

When I however want to view the results in the command window, and have set the intercept to zero, values for `Rquared:Ordinary` and `Rsquared.Adjusted` are not displayed, along with the coefficient, standard errors, p-value, DoF and so on.

It could be the case that I have not understood some principal from basic statistics, but when I imagine a straight line being fit through simple sets of data on a 2-D graph, e.g in the regression: `y ~ a * x`, I still expect a value for `Rsqaured` and `AdjRsquared` to be able to be calculated.

***Are the results I am still being able to pull from the `LinearModel` class definitely valid?***

***Why are the values not shown in the standard output?***

This is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359120/how-to-get-the-fstat-out-of-fitlm-matlab) that also deals with `fitlm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a simple time series, and fit it

```
x = linspace(0, 1, 20);
y = 3*x + 0.2*rand(1, length(x));
mdl = fitlm(x, y, 'linear', 'Intercept', false)
```

You can access the quantities that you need by calling

```
mdl.Coefficients.Estimate
mdl.Rsquared
```

I think that these statistics are not displayed by default because of an arbitrary choice of the developers.